# Terminating a linux kernel thread from userspace

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I am designing a system which is divided between Linux user-space and kernel-space. Both of these components should communicate with each other so I have provided two ways 1) few systemcalls and 2) proc filesystem entry.

To make a long story short I want to provide a way from usersapce to terminate kernel threads and spawn new threads in kernel. I am able to spawn new threads but I am not sure how to terminate threads in kernel space without a disaster.

Has anyone done this? How can I go about it without corrupting structures?

Please if you can share code to terminate kernel threads gracefully that would be great.

Thanks.
Have a great day.

Comment: You shouldn't terminate kernel threads from userspace. You should have a way of requesting that the kernel terminate a particular thread, such as through some kind of `/proc` API if necessary.

Comment: Agreed. I am trying to do just that using stop_kthread. However I am not sure how can I guarantee that all the data will be secure and it wouldn't crash. Are there any known mechanisms for that?